# Web-app to tell me what time a site is most active at?

Tags: gratis, web-apps

Is there a web-app to tell me ***when*** a site is most active (ie. being *most visited by users*), preferably using up-to-date information.

It needs to:

- work on a URL I give it (it does not have to be a URL owned by me)
- tell me the *time* ranges at which there are the highest and lowest number of visitors
- be free

If possible (though not necessary!):

- no registration
- a graph of time and visitors

The data doesn't have to be exact - within a few hours will do!

Comment: Active in what way? User postings to a forum? Updates to an RSS or Twitter feed? The average website doesn't really have any way to gauge "activity" of any kind. "Other relevant stuff" - this is very vague, what is relevant to you?

Comment: From the outside directly to the website this is not very likely to exist. The software would have to hook into the site statistics, and for security reasons nobody is going to allow that.

Comment: @winterblood Sorry - was being a bit vague there - by 'active', I mean 'most visited', so when is a site visited the most by people. Got rid of the last bullet - it was unnecessary I think.

Comment: @JanDoggen I guess so... but there's no harm in hoping one does exist! :)

Comment: You can track the clicks on a specific link, but for websites I think such data is private to the domain owners and those they choose to share it with. For example, anyone gets to see the views on a YouTube video, but only the uploader is allowed (by YouTube) to see more detailed statistics such as the ones you mention. The question is not unclear so I'm voting to reopen, but I agree with @JanDoggen that such a service is unlikely to exist

Comment: @Timmy Seems right :( although I wish you were wrong ;p

Comment: So a bit like Alexa, but split into day hours? Should the hour be universal (for instance UTC) or adjusted to each visitor's probably timezone?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yeah - like Alexa, but I am only really concerned with the time! And preferably UTC, or any, single time zone.